# How to find Mac folders that are missing a specific file

Tags: macos, search, finder

Is there a way to check folders on your Mac for a missing item?

Say I want to scan my external hard drive, and find all of the folders with a certain word in the title, that are missing the file `Data.log`?

What would be the easiest way to go about doing this, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the great answer from @Nifle, but including your specifics try:

```
% find /Volumes/WD -type d -name *[TEST]* | while read a; do if [ ! -f $a/Data.log ]; then echo $a; fi; done
```

Breaking this one-liner down:

- `find /Volumes/WD -type d -name *[TEST]*`: Walks the file tree from `/Volumes/WD` into your external HD looking for directories (`-type d`) which have `[TEST]` somewhere in their name (`-name *[TEST]*`).
- The output from the `find` command is piped (by `|`) into the `bash` `while` loop which pulls matching directories out one at a time storing them in a variable `a`.
- Within the loop:

  - The `if` statement checks that the file `Data.log` isn't in the directory being considered.  In the `if` statement, `$a` is expanded so that `$a/Data.log` is a path like `/Volumes/WD/<dir1>/<dir2>/Data.log`.  To get the test you're interested in  `!` and `-f` are used so that only cases where a file with that name doesn't exist will evaluate to `TRUE` (`!` is `NOT`, and `-f` indicates a file rather than any other type of filesystem entry like directories or links).
  - Finally, if we find a matching directory, it is printed by `echo $a` where `$a` is replaced as above by the directory name piped in from `find`.

I know I'm rehashing a previous answer, but I hope this clears up what is going on in the great one-liner put forward by @Nifle and gets your problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick , run it in a shell.

```
find /Volumes/WD/ -type d -name '*TEST*' | while read a; do if [ ! -f $a/Data.log ]; then echo $a; fi; done;
```

Comment: If you don't want an exact match with certain_word, you might want "*certain_word*"

Comment: Worked a little bit. It's not pulling the information right or something. I want to check all the folders that have the word "[TEST]" in them on the path ->> /Volumes/WD/ , and I want it to show all the folders that are missing Data.log?

Comment: Kind of confusing, I know.

Comment: @Joey - try now. If not what are you getting for errors or result?

Comment: Okay, that's working better, but it's listing everything? haha, it's not listening folders that are missing the file.

Comment: -bash: [: too many arguments